# Pull Filename From Latest File

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code (co-opted from someone here) to access the latest generated files from a folder. I use it to open the file and do various bits (example below). But I was wondering if there is a way to pull the filename from the latest file and paste it into a cell in another workbook?

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    MyPath = "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\folderXXX"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "XYZ-********-123.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No files were found…", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

    Range("B2:D97").Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("New.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Can it been done with the existing code, is it as simple as adding something to this line `Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile` instead of `.Open`?

Appreciate any help or tips even tips to tidy it up in any way. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the entire path or just the filename? `MyPath & LatestFile` is the entire path; `LatestFile` is the filename. Just write whichever one you need to the cell in question.

Comment: Thank you for replying I'm still learning! But every response is great cause I can glean something new each time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    Dim wb As WorkBook, wsDest As Worksheet '<<<

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    MyPath = "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\folderXXX"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "XYZ-********-123.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No files were found…", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Data") '<< for example

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)

    wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2:D97").Copy wsDest.Range("A2")
    wb.Close False '<< don't save

    wsDest.Range("A1").Value = LatestFile '<< record the file name


End Sub
```